# Ninject inject all interfaces and classes automatically C# and MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I want to create some line(s) of code which inject automatically all classes and interfaces.

I thought that is enough to create a base interface like `IBase`

and then

`public interface IManager : IBase { }`

`public interface IService : IBase { }`

and classes

`public class Manager : IManager { }`

`public class Service : IService { }`

Controller's constructor might look like:

`public MyController(IManager manager) { }`

It is possible to register all interfaces and classes which has `IBase` to avoid add one by one like

```
kernel.Bind<IService>().To<Service();
```

?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you're talking about instances where an interface is only implemented by exactly one class?  And the solution is not loading in any other types via reflection at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with usage of convention binding:

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions

Example:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().BindAllInterfaces());
```

This will bind all classes from calling assembly to all implemented interfaces.